# How can I use `workers` in scipy's integration method `integrate.quad_vec`?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, pickle

Scipy's [scipy.integrate.quad_vec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html#scipy.integrate.quad_vec) knows the argument `workers` to parallelise the integration. However, python cannot pickle `lambda` functions. How is the intended use of `workers` then or how can I formulate my integration without the use of the `lambda` function?

I have a function of the following form:

```
sp.integrate.quad_vec(
        lambda x: sp.special.spherical_jn(a, b * (x_0 - x)),
        x_ini,
        x_0,
        workers = -1,
    )
```

which works fine without the `workers` argument. With the workers, `python` throws the following error:

```
Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7f63d939ce00>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a lambda expression, define a function to be passed to `quad_vec`.  I also recommend converting the global variables used in your function to actual parameters of the function, and passing them to `quad_vec` with the `args` parameter.

Here's how I would rewrite the example from the [`quad_vec`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html) docstring to use `workers` (but without the plotting).  This is a script to be run, rather than an interactive session, and the call of `quad_vec` is in the `if` clause guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__"` so the multiprocessing module can import `f` without recursively trying to evaluate `quad_vec`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec


def f(x, alpha):
    return x**alpha


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x0, x1 = 0, 2
    alpha = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, num=30)
    y, err = quad_vec(f, x0, x1, args=(alpha,), workers=-1)
    print(f'{y = }')
```

Comment: Fabulous, that seems to work nicely. Thank you very much. :)